# Verb meaning "enters/affects/holds relevance within each part of my life"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I want to say something along the lines of: "It's remarkable how [a philosophy/way of thinking] seems to _______________ (in/to) all aspects of my life."

I think the word may end in -ize, but I'm really not sure. What is an appropriate verb in a statement like the one above?

Comment: Omnipresent, perhaps.

Comment: *Invade*, perhaps.

Comment: Infiltrate maybe. I would propose "crawls". Atleast in Germany we say "Like sand at the beach, crawling into every crack in which it should not"

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical (*amazing at*), unidiomatic (*sectors of my life*), and the register is all over the place (*amazing* vs philosophy), so the choice of that one word is the least of you problems. Whichever word you pick, it will be a very, very poor sentence. The answerers do recognize that and suggest rewordings, but that amounts to proofreading and is off-topic as such.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Isn't it more constructive to improve the question through edits rather than just point out its issues?

Comment: @pyobum The ELU Help Center says that questions may be considered unsuitable for the site. The 'unclear' close-vote reason is a valid option. ELU is intended as a site for discussion among 'linguists' etc, not for tidying up poor grammar etc.

Comment: There are the basic _influence_ / _affect_ / _inform_; one could include an intensifier (_greatly_ ...). _Dominate_ is what I'd choose.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I understand that this site is not intended as a proofreading service, and this question may end up being closed for other perfectly valid reasons. But I've seen some good questions from non-native speakers that are not in the best shape grammatically. Surely that alone is not a reason to close a question. At any rate, this particular question seems decent enough for a single word request.

Comment: @pyobum I was making a general point. The 'what to do with a good question poorly presented' issue has been addressed on Meta; subscribers often view individual questions in different ways. Thanks for editing it: I'm fairly sure in line with OP's thinking. Probably others have had their fill of second-guessing OPs and choose the less onerous option. There is always the underlying caveat here that people who are _not_ 'linguists' etc [see the Help Center] can find a website other than ELU on which they may ask their questions; there seem few websites other than ELU _intended_ for linguists etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well stated. I've only been a member of the site for a couple of months but it's clear that there's a constant balancing act between maintaining the quality of the questions and keeping the community active. I can't find exactly the right words to describe it, but hopefully you catch what I meant to say.

Answer (score 6):

I propose "pervade"

...seems to pervade my whole life.

Pervade meaning to be present throughout or spread through all areas of something

Answer (score 5):

The word "[**permeates**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/permeate)" works very nicely in the context you've provided.

Permeate is often used in the phrase "X permeates every aspect of Y," and Y is frequently "life/lives." Here are a few examples I grabbed from online sources: a headline--[Ebola crisis permeates every aspect of people's lives](http://www.un.org/apps/news/story.asp?NewsID=49045#.VMCbP1Kmrmg), a line in a movie review--[A love and passion for comics permeates every aspect of the film...](http://exclaim.ca/Film/article/she_makes_comics-marissa_stotter), and a quote--"[Self-respect permeates every aspect of your life." -Joe Clark](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/j/joeclark380944.html)

As in the examples above, I would say that permeate works well in your sentence.

"...it's amazing how Taoism seems to (have) permeate(d) all aspects of my life."

Comment: Or perhaps *infuses*.

Answer (score 0):

Through a process of osmosis or diffusion?

> **OSMOSIS**:
>
> **2**: a process of absorption or diffusion suggestive of the flow of osmotic action; especially : a usually effortless often unconscious assimilation, learned a number of languages by osmosis—Roger Kimball
>
> **DIFFUSE**:
>
> **2**: not concentrated or localized, diffuse lighting; diffuse sclerosis
> — dif•fuse•ly *adverb*; — dif•fuse•ness *noun*

All from **Merriam-Webster** *online*

Answer (score -2):

It's possible you're thinking of "metastasize", although that's usually used of negative things, like cancer.